# Switch statements always executing on the first choice

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm attempting to create a game of rock, paper, scissors. The problem is my switch statement always executes on the first option.
i.e passing a value of
(rock, computer) always generates "you win!"
(scissors, computer) returns "its a tie"
(paper, computer) returns "you lose"

I'm running a set of about 10 ten tests and I notice that the switch statements must be faulty based on my output.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

````
var computer = Math.random()

function game(user, computer)
{
    if (computer < .34)
    {
      computer = "rock";
    }

    else if (computer > .33 && computer < .67)
    {
      computer = "paper";
    }

    else 
    {
      computer = "scissors";
    }
    let result = ""; 

    if (user === "rock")
    {
      switch(computer) 
      {
        case "scissors":
          result = "you win!";
          break;

        case "paper":
          result = "you lose";
          break;

        case "rock":
        result = "its a tie";
        break;
      }
    
    return result;
    }

    else if (user === "paper")
    {
      switch(computer) 
      {
        case "scissors":
          result = "you lose!";
          break;

        case "paper":
          result = "its a tie";
          break;

        case "rock":
          result =  "you win!";
          break;
      }
      return result;
    }


    if (user === "scissors")
    {
      switch(computer)
       {
        case "scissors":
          result = "its a tie";
          break;

        case "paper":
          result =  "you win!";
          break;

        case "rock":
          result = "you lose!";
          break;
      }

      return result;
    }   
}```


describe('gameFunction', ()=>{
    it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('rock', 'scissors')).toBe('you win!');
    })
    it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('rock', 'paper')).toBe('you lose!');
    })
    it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('rock', 'rock')).toBe(`it's a tie`);
    })
    it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('paper', 'rock')).toBe(`you win!`);
    })
    it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('paper', 'scissors')).toBe(`you lose!`);
    })
    it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('paper', 'paper')).toBe(`it's a tie`);
    })
    it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('scissors', 'paper')).toBe(`you win!`);
    })
    it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('scissors', 'rock')).toBe(`you lose!`);
    })
});
````

Comment: Please show us those ten tests where you are calling `game`. Do you really pass a number for the `computer` parameter?

Comment: Are you passing an actual number as the second parameter? If not, your `if` tests will fail and `computer` inside the function will always be assigned `scissors`.

Comment: What value are you passing for computer?
Seems like the value of computer is greater than 0.67 in all of your tests.

Comment: I"ve updated to show the tests  and where I'm declaring computer at the top as a random number on each call .

Comment: Why you are using if else statements that are comparing it with  .34, .33, .67? Your issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are generating a random number for computer variable using random function, but you are using it wrongly. Though it is global but since we have computer as parameter in the game function, that variable will be used.

It will consider those values which you are passing to it.

For Example:
You are passing scissors for computer variable in this call `expect(functions.game('rock', 'scissors')).toBe('you win!');`. Your function will compare `scissors` with `.34`, `.33`,`.67`. These checks will always be false in this case and else part will be executed.

You need to pass the value of random variable instead of `rock`,`scissors` and `paper` as second argument in function.

Answer (score 0):

In your tests, you are passing in a string as the second (`computer`) argument. For example, this test passes 'scissors':

```
   it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('rock', 'scissors')).toBe('you win!');
    })
```

But your `game` function expects to be given a number (as would be generated by Math.random()).

The confusion is probably related to the fact that you are declaring a global variable named `computer`:

```
var computer = Math.random()
```

But when you use that same identifier as a parameter name for your function, your function has no visibility to that global. That is, any reference to `computer` inside your function will refer to the *parameter* named `computer`, not to the global variable you declared named `computer`.

One way you could fix this up is by passing numbers to your function in your tests:

```
 it('return win, lose or tie', ()=>{
        expect(functions.game('rock', 0.1)).toBe('you win!');
 })
```